# How do you auto generate a function pointer table?

Tags: c, cmake, build, auto-generate

Let's say I have a file *math.c*:

```
#include <stdint.h>

int32_t add(int16_t a, int16_t b)
{
    return a + b;
}

int32_t sub(int16_t a, int16_t b)
{
    return a - b;
}
```

a file *main.c*:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void func()
{
    printf("func()\n");
}

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

and I compile those 2 files together into a single executable.

**Here is the question**, I want to have an automated process for creating a new file during build (*autogen.c*) with a table holding all of the function addresses, like this:

```
const uint32_t func_table[] =
{
    (uint32_t)add,
    (uint32_t)sub,
    (uint32_t)func,
    (uint32_t)main,
};
```

The plan is to use this table elsewhere in the code, e.g:

```
extern const uint32_t func_table[];

void mock_func(uint32_t func_id)
{
    address = func_table[func_id];
    // ...
}
```

At first I thought, assuming I have a way to get all function-names, I can create this table pretty easily with a simple python script, but then I realized that it wouldn't compile if the functions are not declared in the same file (explicitly or via include), so now I need to get the full function signature which I don't know how.

I'm using *cmake* + *gcc*, and python scripts are already running as pre-build steps.
Can you recommend on any tools or give other advise that will help achieve that?

Comment: why do you think that 32 bits will be enough to store function address?

Comment: @0___________ I should have mentioned it, but it's specifically for a 32 bit system.

Comment: On Unix-like systems, the `nm` program will give you a "name list" of all the symbols in an object file. So try `nm main.o math.o` to get a feel for its output. You'll want to pick out the global text or capital-T symbols. (You can pipe to `grep`, or there are probably command-line options.)

Comment: "so now I need to get the full function signature which I don't know how." - In C, a function's signature does not become a part of the symbol name. So in the `autogen.c` you may safely declare every function as e.g. ``void add(void);``.

Comment: I don't understand the problem. Why don't you declare the functions in some "math.h" (terrible name! you can't use that, but that's another story) if you intend to use them in other .c files?

Comment: @Tsyvarev interesting, will checkout this direction, thanks!

Comment: @Lundin it's an option but then it wouldn't be automated, I don't have a single C file that I want to take the function pointers from, but many C files. I want ALL function pointers in the program, preferably without having to include each new header in the autogen file.